# need clear php "->" symbol explanation in Yii CActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii

i just learn yii framework, i need explanation about this part of code

```
$model=TblUser::model()->findByPk($id);
```

what i understand so far are:

1. $model is a variable
2. TblUser is class named TblUser.php
3. model() is static method
4. findByPk($id) is a method

is that right?, then i try to open model method inside TblUser class, but i cant find where findByPk() is located?, and what **CLASS** mean?

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii, every table model extends `CActiveRecord` class. `CActiveRecord` implements **CRUD**(Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations in the **ORM**(Object Relational Mapping) approach. So, `findByPk`, `find`, `save`, `update`, `delete` and so many other methods are parts of the `CActiveRecord` class.
When you use `$model=TblUser::model()->findByPk($id)`, first, the static `model()` function inside the `TblUser` class will be called. `model()` function returns parent class of `TblUser` class(`CActiveRecord` in fact). And finally `findByPk` method of `CActiveRecord` will be executed.

Comment: thanks hamed for your answer, could you tell me where CActiveRecord class is located?, before i mark your answer

Comment: You are welcome! `framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php`.